# Angular2 Iterate JSON in component

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am trying iterate JSON with differents datas.

I am using Angular2, Ag-grid Master detail , with template in detailCellRendererParams:

I have a problem when I try iterate my JSON for get data.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};
    this.detailCellRendererParams = {
      detailGridOptions: {
        onGridReady: function(params) {
          params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
        }
      },

      getDetailRowData: function(params) {},

  template: function(params) {
    console.log('before');
    console.log('datas ', params.data.masterdetail);
    for (const valor of params.data.masterdetail) {
      console.log('eyy');
      if (params.data.masterdetail.hasOwnProperty(valor)) {
        console.log('este valor es : ', valor);
      }
    }
    console.log('after');
    // console.log('template ', params.data.masterdetail);
    return '<div class="aggrid--full-row-container">' + '<div ref="eDetailGrid" </div>' + 'asereje ' + '</div>';
  }
 };
}
```

Never join the for...

[image]

You can see how I get `4` datas in   `console.log('datas ', params.data.masterdetail);`

New Code Update:

```
 console.log('before');
 console.log('datas ', params.data.masterdetail);
 const objects = JSON.parse(params.data.masterdetail);
    for (const obj of objects) {
      const keys = Object.keys(obj);
      keys.forEach(key => {
        console.log(obj[key]);
      });
    }
    console.log('after');
```

Error:

```
ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at template (projectunits.component.ts:43)
at DetailCellRenderer.webpackJsonp../node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/rendering/detail/detailCellRenderer.js.DetailCellRenderer.selectAndSetTemplate (detailCellRenderer.js:96)
at DetailCellRenderer.webpackJsonp../node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/rendering/detail/detailCellRenderer.js.DetailCellRenderer.init (detailCellRenderer.js:33)
at ComponentResolver.webpackJsonp../node_modules/ag-
```

[image]

I get this datas the un file.json.
Structure the my Json:

```
{

 "headers": [ 
   "headerName": "asdasd",
 ],   //end headers

  "datas": [

  "idaam": "11",
  "idorigen": "11",

   "masterdetail": {
        "child1": {
          "name": "I AM",
          "age": "1"

        },

        "child2": {
          "name": "YOU ARE",
          "age": "2"
        },

        "child3": {
        "name": "HE IS",
        "age": "3"
        },
    } //end masterdetail
  ]//end datas

}//end JSON
```

Comment: updated my answer please try out

Comment: can you check the length of `params.data.masterdetail` in console showing or undefined

Comment: I updated with more code and my Json

Comment: your `"masterdetail"` value should be this format  
`"masterdetail": [{"child1":{"name":"I AM","age":"1"}},{"child2":{"name":"YOU ARE","age":"2"}},{"child3":{"name":"HE IS","age":"3"}}]`
then you can iterate properly.

Comment: are you sure its json , because JSON.prase is not working as you tole me

Comment: can you able to share code at stackbiz, i am working with ag-grid and never found it  returns json

Comment: can you try `JSON.stringify(`, updated my answer

Comment: Yes I need " [ ] " but I can't iterate child1,child2 ... I use params.data.masterdetail.forEach((data)=>{
});

Answer (score 0):

seeem like its not json data can you try

```
params.data.masterdetail.forEach((data)=>{
});
```

---

As its json , you should part json to object and then do for on that

```
 const objects = JSON.prase(JSON.stringify(params.data.masterdetail));
 for(const obj of objects){
   const keys = Object.keys(obj);
   keys.forEach((key)=> {
    console.log(obj[key]);
  });
 }
```

Comment: @EduBw - then its not json data i guess

Comment: @EduBw - can you try foreach on you object

Comment: Error : params.data.masterdetail.forEach is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Here is my anwser. You might check if the data is an Object or a simple String before parsing. This code assumes that you are sure you are getting a a JSON instead of an Array

```
const objects = (typeof params.data.masterdetail == 'object') ?  JSON.parse(params.data.masterdetail) : params.data.masterdetail;
for (const obj in objects) {
  const data = objects[obj];
  //Bellow if each attribute data
}
```

Comment: core.js:1449 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at template (projectunits.component.ts:45)
    at DetailCellRenderer.webpackJsonp../node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/rendering/detail/detailCellRenderer.js.DetailCellRenderer.selectAndSetTemplate

Comment: Yeah just tell us what is the content of params.data.masterdetail